# Add multiple MySQL entries together

Tags: mysql, addition

I have a database with posts in it, to make it simpler, say I have two fields "user" and "rate". I want to select all of the ratings from all of the posts by user: "Joe" and add them together and display them. Then I want to do the same with the other users, to produce a leaderboard.
I do not know the names of the users in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below produce only one result which is the totalrate for user JOE

```
SELECT SUM(Rate) totalRate
FROM tableName
WHERE user = 'joe'
```

this one will show the user with the greatest rate because it was sorted based on the totalRate in descending order

```
SELECT user, SUM(rate) totalRate
FROM tableName
-- WHERE user = 'JOE'
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY totalRate DESC
```

Comment: That is what I was trying, but it means I have to enter the actual username. I am trying to find something that will automatically get the usernames